# Como pegar os dados da notificação com onNewIntent

Tags: android, firebase

Possuo uma aplicação na qual quando clico na notificação gostaria de pegar os valores setados na notificação putExtra dentro de onNewIntent, segue meu código para ver se alguém consegue me ajudar.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("id",id);
    i.putExtra("plan",plan);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Agora no MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);

    String id;
    String plan;
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(extras == null) {
        Log.w("extras", "false");
        id= null;
        plan= null;
    } else {
        if(extras.getString("id") != "" && extras.getString("plan") != "") {
            Log.w("extras", "true");
            id= extras.getString("id");
            plan= extras.getString("plan");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual é o problema? Entra no método `onNewIntent()` e o Bundle é nulo? Ou nem sequer entra no método?

Comment: O valor era nulo, consegui rodar removendo a linha setIntent(intent);